# Can't add a picklist to a form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I've created a field *picky* but when I try to actually put in onto the form of my entity, I can't. I'm pulling it out hovering over a place to set it **but** the red line marking the drop-off spot doesn't show.

I remember very clearly it did in my last Project. In fact, I went back to the previous customer's GUI and tried the same and it worked there. I suspect it might have to do with the different versions. The customer runs on-premise (4.0 or 2011), the new project is on-line (2011) and I wonder how it's going to be in the next version (2013).

1. What can be causing it?
2. What can I do about it?

Comment: Might be a browser issue, tried from another PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Incompatibility in IE 10.
2. (a) Run IE9/IE8 (works **always**).
   (b) Try to run IE10 in backwards compatibility mode (works often).
   (c) Wait for an update for CRM/IE10 (works slowly and seldom).

As a side note, I can tell that when I was having that issue, I noticed that by using a remote desktop to our development environment (or at least a virtual machine, e.g. VirtualBox, wouldn't you have access to an external environment), one could omit the whole issue sans having to degrade to an earlier version of IE.